# Unicode Javascript - Need to display invalid characters back to user

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

I'm looking for a solution that will solve the following problem but only have limited experience with Unicode.

Basically the user is able to type into a text field, however when they submit i want to display a list of the characters that **WEREN"T** GSM compliant. I.E everything that doesn't have a char code of 0-127.

However, it breaks severely when you bring emojis into the mix because if i char array it some emoji characters will get broken up and it will display the wrong reason why the validation failed.

I.E "".length = 2, it will get split into 2 characters and therefore when i tell the user why it failed they will get the wrong reason.

Any ideas on how i can solve this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Can't use ES6 and need an array of the invalid characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you’re using a regex like this to find characters that aren’t in the valid range:

```
/[^\0-\x7f]/
```

you can modify it to prefer to match [UTF-16 surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16):

```
/[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[^\0-\x7f]/
```

On modern browsers, you can also just use the `u` flag to operate on Unicode codepoints directly:

```
/[^\0-\x7f]/u
```

This will still only get codepoints, though, and not grapheme clusters (important for combining characters, modern combined emoji, skin tone, and general correctness in all languages). Those are harder to deal with. When (if?) [browser support appears](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter), they will be less hard; until then, [a dedicated package](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) is your best bet.

```js
var NON_GSM_CODEPOINT = /[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[^\0-\x7f]/;
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function () {
  var match = this.value.match(NON_GSM_CODEPOINT);
  this.setCustomValidity(match ? 'Invalid character: “' + match[0] + '”' : '');
  this.form.reportValidity();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: What if i wanted to display all the matched characters? not just one

Comment: EDIT: 
this updated regex gave me all the matched characters. Solved thanks
var NON_GSM_CODEPOINT = /[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[^\0-\x7f]/g;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator (`...`) to break the characters into an array and then `charCodeAt` to get the value:

```js
let str = `abcdefghi`;
let chars = [...str];

console.log(`All Chars: ${chars}`);

console.log('Bad Chars:',
  chars.filter(v=>v.charCodeAt(0)>127)
);
```

Comment: Hah even more ES6-y than `Array.from`

Comment: @Gizmox what about standard replace `str.replace(/\w/g,'')`, which will remove all `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! This is merely trial and error, but looks like converting the string to an array of <strike>chars</strike> strings using `Array.from` will allow you to index the characters correctly:

```
Array.from('').length
1

Array.from('abc').length
4

Array.from('abc')[0]
""
```